# Two ListLinePlots together with two vertical axes

Tags: plotting

I have two data sets `data1` and `data2`:

```
SeedRandom[1];
data1 = Sort[RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]];
data2 = Sort[RandomReal[2, {10, 2}]];
```

I would like to plot both data sets in one common plot with two different colors.

- the left vertical scale should extend from 0 to 1 for `plot1`
- the right vertical scale should extend from 0 to 2 for `plot2`

How can I do that?

Comment: @Kuba: Thank this seems to help ... but I do now see any numbers at the right axis: http://imgur.com/a/fwypI

Comment: @Kuba: Could you please show the code for my example? I am not able to make it running.

Comment: @JasonB. it is at least documented. If your code fails one can't even complain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1];
data1 = Sort[RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]];
data2 = Sort[RandomReal[2, {10, 2}]];
```

Something about the grouping for `Frame`, `FrameStyle` and `FrameTicks` is a bit out of date in the previous answer. Try

```
plot1 = ListPlot[data1,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
  PlotStyle -> Blue,
  ImagePadding -> 25,
  Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}}, 
  FrameStyle -> {{Blue, Automatic}, {Blue, Blue}}
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
plot2 = ListPlot[data2,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 2}},
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  ImagePadding -> 25,
  Axes -> False,
  Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}},
  FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}, 
  FrameStyle -> {{Automatic, Red}, {Automatic, Red}}
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Overlay[{plot1, plot2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for your help. Why is the right vertical axis (red) not positioned at x=1?

Comment: @lio I am away from my computer. Maybe try `ImagePadding` as in previous answer

Comment: Great ... yes this has to be added: for both plots `ImagePadding -> 25,`. Could you please update your answer?

Comment: @lio Updated with `ImagePadding`

Comment: Is it possible to align the y-axes? If I have one data set with just positive y values and another one with also negative y values then the two y-axes are misaligned. `AxesOrigin` doesn't seem to work here.